# Plugin to display Yaml, Xml, PHP like on Symfony2 documentation

Tags: javascript, symfony

On symfony2.com documentation site there are often code examples (selected yaml by default). I can switch (via small tabs) format to display from Yaml to Xml or PHP. I wonder if this is a javascript plugin? Do you know what is the origin of this? I would like to use similar thing on my website.

Here is an example http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html
- section "Step 1: Create the Route"

Comment: I think they use sphinx for documentation.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper is right. They use Sphinx, which is a python library, using customized markdown.

Comment: Yes i do know they are using Sphinx to create a documentation but question is not about this. If you look at my link provided you can see (scroll down) code examples that look like notes with tabs (yaml, xml, php). I need to know how they are created? I would like to use this plugin if it exists. Thanks